# GetSymbolInfo returning null for attribute in source generator

Tags: c#, code-generation, .net-7.0, xunit.net, c#-10.0

I'm trying to make a source generator that's triggered based on an attribute being set on the class.  I'm wanting to get the name of the class that's decorated with the attribute, but when I run the below method, `info.Symbol` is always `null`.  I know this can happen when references aren't properly set, but I think that's not happening here because the `attribute` shows the correct item.

```cs
private static ClassDeclarationSyntax? GetSemanticTargetForGeneration(GeneratorSyntaxContext context) {
    if (context.Node is not ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclarationSyntax)
        return null;

    foreach (var attributeList in classDeclarationSyntax.AttributeLists)
        foreach (var attribute in attributeList.Attributes) {
            var info = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(attribute);
                
            if (info.Symbol is not INamedTypeSymbol symbol)
                continue;

            ...
        }

    return null;
}
```

I'm using the following test helper class (with Verify.XUnit 20.8.1 and Verify.SourceGenerators 2.1.0) where I explicitly add the assembly to the compilation's reference.

```cs
public static Task Verify(string source) {
    var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

    var references = new PortableExecutableReference[] {
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(LaMP.API.RepositoryAttribute).Assembly.Location)
    };

    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Test", new[] {
            syntaxTree
        }, references);

    var target = CSharpGeneratorDriver.Create(new RepositorySourceGenerator()).RunGenerators(compilation);
        
    return Verifier
        .Verify(target)
        .UseDirectory("Snapshots");
}
```